# Type guards for exportable utility functions: isNull, isNullOrWhitespace, etc

Tags: typescript

I have a React project with Typescript in which I frequently use some utility functions: `isFunction`, `isNull`, `isNullOrEmpty`, `isNullOrWhitespace`, and so on.

I can have something like this in my utility file:

```
export const isNull = (value: any): boolean => value === null || value === undefined;
```

And then I will use it elsewhere like so (very contrived example):

```
const customFunction(arrayOfObjects?: any[]) => {
    if (!isNull(arrayOfObjects)) {
        // do something here, e.g.:
        arrayOfObjects?.map((c) => ...); // line 4
    }
}
```

Of course, Typescript still thinks that the type of `arrayOfObjects` in line 4 is still `any[] | undefined`, even though it's certainly not null or undefined if it made it inside this block. So I found out the correct way to handle this is using type guards. If I instead change my utility function like so:

```
export const isNull = (value: any): value is null | undefined => value === null || value === undefined;
```

Then the `isNull` check works as expected, and correctly detects that `arrayOfObjects` on line 4 is not null or undefined.

The problem I am then having is type-checking more advanced functions. I wouldn't want to call `arrayOfObjects.map()` unless I knew that `arrayOfObjects` was not null, undefined, an object, or an empty array. So I want to define a function `isNullOrEmpty` that will return false for e.g. `{}, [], null, undefined`, but throwing these into the type guard

```
export const isNullOrEmpty = (value: any): value is ({} | [] | null | undefined) => {...}
```

results in:

```
const customFunction(arrayOfObjects?: any[]) => {
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(arrayOfObjects)) {
        arrayOfObjects?.map((c) => ...); // Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'
    }
}
```

I have similar issues when dealing with checking for a function:

```
export const isFunction = (value: any): boolean => typeof value === 'function';
```

Or checking that ([Potentially related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42101)?):

```
export const isNullOrWhitespace = (value: any): boolean => isNullOrEmpty(value) || (typeof (value) === 'string' && !value.trim());
```

Particularly because I am so often checking that something is *not* null or whitespace, so I am not sure how to grab the negation of those types as well.

What is the correct way to export functions that can type check?

Comment: _"I wouldn't want to call arrayOfObjects.map() unless I knew that arrayOfObjects was not null, undefined, an object, or an empty array."_ Well, `.map()` can not be called on objects, so really you are only looking for an array here. Objects and arrays are very different. So I think you will be much better served by looking for what a value _is_ rather than what it _isn't_.

Comment: As an example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGBBRAtgBygTwIIBOBAhjgDwAqiApgB5TVgAmAzouANYoDuYA2gF0AfAAoAbsQA2IagC5EVAD7IQkyYmXgm1YDDDUmASnkTp1RDDZUA3gChEDxAWpQQBJAEIPpmYgBkfog+1AB0kowA5lAAFohCiAAMtgC+trYQCCxQiBAgWXDoAGLg0PBIALyIIsREpADywHUARgBW1NAsAPzynDz8AoaI5fF2jhbAVShgGNj4tTjV8w3NbR2Gg6NjjjUkOMut7VBdIejEmCIiEIPDOYYA3IgA9I+Iuvr2jqmp6ZnZuflFEqwBAAJiGVRYBWoK0O3XYYC4cF41xGHwcMAmIimM1whF2Ikh6GhB2g60Qmy2TxedEwhwMiFwtJoRDgBAANIgmu1iHlzAADQnE1ZQPmIU44ZBwbJcxDEJA7UghBTRSwWNjERAROBwJgMlVgCIhNGIL5AA

Comment: Hi @AlexWayne, yes I am aware, it was a contrived example. I have a function in which I want values of `null, undefined, {}, []` to return false. I know that I can't call "`.map()` on an object. If I had a catch-all `isNullOrEmpty()` function that did so, I could call that before .map(). E.g. I'd return false if it were a function, if `value.length === 0`, or `Object.keys(value).length === 0)`, etc. I need help with the Typescript part, not the `isNullOrEmpty` part-- it's a utility function I call all over the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here.

```
export const isNullOrEmpty = (value: any): value is ({} | [] | null | undefined) => {...}
//                                                   ^
```

The `{}` is not an empty object. Object types actually mean that they require *at least* the keys they specify, but they could have more:

```
const objA = { a: 123, b: 456 }
const objB: { a: number } = objB // fine
```

Here `objA` has at least all the keys required by the type of `objB`, so the assignment is allowed.

Following that logic, the `{}` type is an object type that requires at zero keys. Which means *almost anything* can be assigned to it, since every value has at least zero keys.

```
const objA = { a: 123, b: 456 }
const testA: {} = objA // fine
const testB: {} = true // fine
const testC: {} = 456 // fine
```

---

[ESLint even has a rule for this pitfall](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/)

> Avoid the Object and {} types, as they mean "any non-nullish value". This is a point of confusion for many developers, who think it means "any object type".
>
> [See this comment for more information.](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492)

---

So when your type predicate function says that a value is `{}`, and you negate that, you are saying that your value is not assignable to `{}`, which as mentioned nearly everything is. So the result is `never`.

---

A better type for an empty object is:

```
Record<string, never>
```

This is an object type that has *exactly* zero keys. It's keys must be a subset of `string`, and the value of those keys must also match the type of `never`. And since `never` cannot actually exist at runtime, this means the object must be actually empty.

So all `string` keys must not have a value.

So replace `{}` with that record type, and your code works.

```
export const isNullOrEmpty = (value: any):
    value is (Record<string, never> | [] | null | undefined) => {
        return true // implementation TBD
    }

const customFunction = (arrayOfObjects?: any[]) => {
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(arrayOfObjects)) {
        arrayOfObjects?.map((c) => c); // fine
    }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wJaoHIFcA2+A8lAKIC2YMAnnALxwAUAbgIb67ABccry1ASi4AoOGLhsOwOFiYAlYEigATADzooGZAHMANHGTBmwKAD44AHzgBtALqWDBfA9zJlwAGZbgygfXMA3qLiIVDAMLhQyHAwUJxwAPQJMpT4wOTAyDCsMBgocAAqAEIAIsFiAL7Cwkho8Ai46BDkAGKuCLn5DIysUFCs1EQeRABGAFaKMKgA-Dx81HZ+dIHlMh5MAIRYeIQkFFTUPX0DQ6MTHagCfkEhIb39g8PjkzMAdOSsYIyMCEvmvwBuRLJLyGVZVCpAA)

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Before I mark it accepted I just want to make sure I understand: if I make another utility function that combines previous functions, e.g. `const isNullOrEmpty = (value: any) => !isFunction(value)
&& (isEmptyArray(value) || isEmptyObject(value));` then I just need to keep concatenating the `value is ...` ? E.g. for `isNullOrEmpty = (value: any): value is (Record<string, never> | [] | null | undefined) => ...`? Is that right?

Comment: I believe that type predicate function don't deeply nest their inferences. So yeah you'd have to do that. But I feel like I should mention you shouldn't have to nest these. These functions are just duplicating safety that typescript gives you. You probably don't want to refactor a whole codebase that uses this a lot, but having worked on multiple very large typescript projects, I've opted to do type narrowing in place like `if (Array.isArray(foo)) foo.map(...)` rather than have a library of functions to do it for me. But without real examples, I can't really advise more.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. Just curious, is there any reason that `{}` is represented as a `Record<string, never>` instead of `Record<any, never>`? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Should be the same, though `any` is a bit broader obviously. But `any` types are best avoided if possible. The completely "correct" type here is probably `Record<PropertyKey, never>`. `PropertyKey` is a built in type that is `string | number | symbol`, which are the only types an object key is allowed to be.